# What type of jasmine is this? Will it survive the cold?

Tags: identification

What type of jasmine is this? Will it tolerate the cold, say -5°C?

The seller told me it is evergreen and will definitely tolerate the cold. But I couldn't believe him. I am now not sure if I should plant it in the garden or keep it in a pot to be able to move it in in the winter. He also told me it's a climbing type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  impossible to  know which variety it is at this stage.  *Jasminum mesnyi* is evergreen and has yellow flowers, but is half hardy and needs a minimum temperature of 7degC. The leaves in your image rule out Jasminum beesianium and J. stephanense, but are correct for either *Jasminum officinale* or *Jasminum polyanthum*; the former is not evergreen, the latter is evergreen with pink flower buds and white flowers, but needs minimum temperatures of 10degC, though in a very sheltered, sunny spot, may well survive the occasional drop down to 5 deg C. So it depends on the colour of the buds and flowers in terms of identifying which one you have.

There are other evergreen Jasmines, but they are not climbers, forming a shrub instead (*Jasminum humile* for instance). Usually, when people say 'evergreen jasmine', they are referring to an entirely different plant - *Trachelospermum jasminoides*, common name star jasmine, but your plant is not that either.